# Selecting an id with inner join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join

I'm trying to construct an user profile, so I'm showing all her likes from the database.
But I want to look if the user that have the active session has liked some of the user profile likes.

So, the table name is loves and the structure is:

```
photo_id (int)
nick     (varchar)
date     (timestamp)
```

photos table structure:

```
photo_id (int)
path     (varchar)
title    (varchar)
category (varchar)
nick     (varchar)
date     (timestamp)
```

This is how I'm traying to do the query:

```
SELECT photos.photo_id
FROM photos
INNER JOIN loves ON loves.nick = 'userProfileName'
WHERE loves.nick =  'userWithActiveSession'
AND photos.photo_id = loves.photo_id
ORDER BY loves.photo_id DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

This query should return all photo ID's that the user with active session have liked with the liked photos from the profile requested user.

**EXAMPLE**

```
loves table:

nick         photo_id
userProfile  26  
userProfile  1000  
userProfile  27
userProfile  520
userSession  26  
userSession  680  
userSession  1000
```

So the query should return only two photos_id (1000 and 26), because both users has liked the same photo_id.

Is there any way to modify this code to do what I want?

Comment: What is the table structure for `photos`?

Comment: Do you want to have the photo IDs of the photos **both** like or the IDs of the photos that **one of them** likes?

Comment: Sorry, look the edited post.

Comment: Only the photos id from the photos table when the user with active session likes some of the "likes" from the user profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want all the photos owned by X (photos.nick = X) and liked by Y?

```
SELECT photos.photo_id FROM photos INNER JOIN loves
ON loves.photo_id = photos.photo_id 
WHERE loves.nick = Y AND photos.nick = X
ORDER BY photos.photo_id DESC LIMIT 100
```

If you want photos liked by both X and Y then you need to join loves to itself, matching the photo_ids from the two copies of the table to each other, and conditioning that one table's nick matches X and the other's matches Y.  (See comments)

Comment: No, I want to get the photo_id when the user Y likes the same photo_id that the user X

Comment: You want to find photo_ids that both X and Y like?  Then you have to join loves to itself.  `SELECT _a.photo_id FROM loves _a INNER JOIN loves _b ON _a.photo_id = _b.photo_id WHERE _a.nick = X AND _b.nick = Y`

Answer (score 1):

you could get the photo_id without join like this:

```
  SELECT   photo_id
  FROM     loves
  WHERE    photo_id in (select photo_id from loves where nick = "userProfile" )
  AND      photo_id in (select photo_id from loves where nick = "userSession" )
  GROUP BY photo_id
  ORDER BY loves.photo_id DESC 
  LIMIT    100
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4191/11)

Comment: some sample data from your tables and the desired result please if you can. edit your question and add them

Comment: I'm trying to get the "likes" from an user profile, and then see if that likes match with the logged user likes!

Comment: Two users = 'userProfile' and 'userSession'.
the 'userProfile' user have 4 likes: (photo_id 26, photo_id 250, photo_id 580, photo_id 1000).
The 'userSession' user have 3 likes; (photo_id 26, photo_id 27, photo_id 1000)

So the query should return the id's 26 and 1000

Comment: same sample data . make some data of your tables and add them to your question,

Comment: Edited, look again the post.

Comment: I only need to get the photo_id,

Comment: u dont need to join the second table of photos?

Comment: Yes, but only to get ehe phto_id.
Or it's possible to get that data without join in photos table?

Answer (score 0):

That part looks weird:

```
INNER JOIN loves ON loves.nick = 'userProfileName'
```

shouldn't it be (assuming there is a nick field on photos table):

```
INNER JOIN loves ON loves.nick = photos.nick
```

or I didn't get something here?